# Javascript function and iframe call on single anchor tag

Tags: javascript, iframe

As per my requirement I want a anchor tag to trigger three actions

1)call a javascript function
2)go to href link.
3)open that link in iframe

here is code for that.

```
<a target="frame1" href="subView" onclick="follow(event, this);">Hi</a>

<iframe name="frame1" src="Date.jsp">
</iframe>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function follow(e, item) {
    e = e || window.event;  //IE stuff
    e.preventDefault();     //prevent link click triggering
    e.returnValue = false;  //also prevent link click triggering (old IE style)
    alert(item.href);
  //    showBreadCrum(item.href);
}
</script>
```

How Can I achieve it.Because all these three things is not happening at the same time.

Comment: okay I got the solution if we comment out the three lines of e then we can achieve it. e = e || window.event;  //IE stuff
    e.preventDefault();     //prevent link click triggering
    e.returnValue = false;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay I got the solution if we comment out the three lines of e then we can achieve it. `e = e || window.event; //IE stuff e.preventDefault(); //prevent link click triggering e.returnValue = false;`